# I can't see my window with FullscreenWindow

Tags: java, swing, fullscreen

Everything is black.

```
btnFullScreen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
                GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
                if (gd.isFullScreenSupported()) {
                    gd.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

```
 GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
                GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
                if (gd.isFullScreenSupported()) {
                    gd.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
                }
```

The `gd.setFullScreenWindow(frame);` function requires that frame is not visible prior to this function invocation:

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html#setFullScreenWindow%28java.awt.Window%29):

> When entering full-screen mode, if the window to be used as a
>   full-screen window *is not visible*, this method will make it visible.
>   It will remain visible when returning to windowed mode.
>
> When entering full-screen mode, all the translucency effects are reset
>   for the window. Its shape is set to null, *the opacity value is set to
>   1.0f, and the background color alpha is set to 255 (completely opaque)*. These values are not restored when returning to windowed
>   mode.
>
> It is unspecified and platform-dependent how decorated windows operate
>   in full-screen mode. For this reason, it is recommended to turn off
>   the decorations in a Frame or Dialog object by using the
>   setUndecorated method.

**What is wrong with : `jFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);`**

**Edit:** a demo to support my claim, And this is what we call [**SSCCE**](http://sscce.org/)
I have a button too, the frame is minimized to the button's size. Click on the button to see in action of `setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)` function.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class MyWindow extends JFrame
{
    int width=GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds().width;
    int height=GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds().height;
    public MyWindow ()
    {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton button = new JButton("Click Me");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            }
        });

        add(button);
        pack();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new MyWindow().setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

---

**Edit: From your below comment:**

> Yes,but i want fullscreen,because my application already obtains to be
>   maximized.

You are probably after the function: `jFrame.setUndecorated(true);`, which will remove the title bar and all to make the frame contain the full screen.

Comment: I went looking for the JavaDocs on that method when the question was asked, but got distracted.  +1 for not only providing an answer, but also for the pointer to `setExtendedState`.

Comment: *"How to do that?"*  What 'that'?  Be specific.

Comment: setExtendedState doesn't function.

Comment: @Esley, no it will perfectly work. I have posted a demo with my answer. Just copy and paste it to see.

Comment: Yes,but i want fullscreen,because my application already obtains to be maximized.

Comment: I think @Esley means that they want it where there is no menu bar and all that....like when playing a game, and it loads to fullscreen mode to view it on the entire screen space

Comment: @Esley, check the edit i put at the end of my answer

Comment: It seems more like a fullscreen application now :)

Comment: I cannot use the setUndecorated in the constructor

Comment: I have that to use in action listener, this is the problem